# Warning: no class variable LanRouter::debug_

Tags: networking, ns2

I've been trying to run a bus topology code using LAN but I keep getting an error

warning: no class variable LanRouter::debug_

see tcl-object.tcl in tclcl for info about this warning."

I've tried to change the code a bit and also include the line

`LanRouter set debug_ 0`

That line just makes the code not run at all in linux, it just does nothing. What can I do to resolve this issue ?

```
set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf


proc finish {} {
    global ns nf
    $ns flush-trace
    close $nf
    #Executenam on the trace file
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]

set lan0 [$ns newLan "$n0 $n1 $n2 $n3 $n4" 0.5Mb 40ms LL Queue/DropTail MAC/Csma/Cd Channel]

set tcp0 [new Agent/TCP]
$tcp0 set class_ 1
$ns attach-agent $n1 $tcp0
set sink0 [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n3 $sink0
$ns connect $tcp0 $sink0

set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr0 set packetSize_ 500
$cbr0 set interval_ 0.01
$cbr0 attach-agent $tcp0

$ns at 0.5 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 4.5 "$cbr0 stop"


$ns at 5.0 "finish"

$ns run
```

Answer (score 1):

First : A warning is not an error. A warning is an informational text.

The setting `LanRouter set debug_ 0` should be e.g. at "line 1" .....

```
# http://forum.shiburaj.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11&sid=0490c83d0f777154e467deef7ec3fb74
# New file name : Bus-topo-1.tcl
#**************************************************#
# Aim : To monitor traffic for Bus topology using NS2
#**************************************************#
#LanRouter set debug_ 1
LanRouter set debug_ 0    

#Create a simulator object
set ns [new Simulator]

#Open the nam trace file
set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf
```

Link, Bus-topo-1.tcl https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymkrtrudd1q9wiy/Bus-topo-1.tcl?dl=0

All ~3500 ns2 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing